# Read C# dictionary to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

How can I read C# dictionary to Javascript in MVC3 without Razor? I can do this fine with newer MVC with

```
var texts = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.TextDict));
```

But my older project does not recognize Jsoncovert. I tried with:

```
var texts = <% Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.TextDict)); %>
```

But here the texts is undefined.

Comment: Add a Json.Net reference, preferable [via NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) to get [`JsonConvert.SerializeObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm).

Comment: I support @UweKeim, you are going to save a lot of time and effort.

Comment: That will be done later when complete project is lifted to newer version. I got this working now with Ludovics help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That because `<% ... %>` simply execute the code inside and doesn't return anything. You should use `<%= ... %>` instead. Try this:

```
var texts = <%= Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.TextDict)); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var texts = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.TextDict));
```